# How do EmguCV detectors relate to EmguCV DescriptorExtractors?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, feature-detection

Reading EmgCV docs cant quite understand: what detectors can be used with which DescriptorExtractors?

[Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/FAST_feature_detector_in_CSharp) it is said:

```
You can use it with the FREAK descriptor that is scale invariant. Just replace the BriefDescriptorExtractor with Freak and it should do the trick.
```

does it mean that not all detectors are compatable to DescriptorExtractors? If yes where one can find comparisons and documentation on topic?

Answer (score 0):

Check these docs as they seem to cover your question:
http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/22ff1e882604fab803baeee7b0535a9d0613b35a/tree/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.rst#id5
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html